# change search path for cordova_plugin.js

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I use NetBeans 7.4 to build an HTML5 bases web app, where the application loads the cordova.js from /js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordovaAndroid.js"></script>
```

this `cordovaAndroid.js` (standard cordova.js for android platform) automatically loads an file called `cordava_plugins.js` from webroot: `/`

So my question is: how and where can i change the path for this plugin file?

I know, that this is possible by changing the `js/cordovaAndroid.js` But in this case, I have to remember that cahnge after every update of the `cordova.js`. I think: hacking an 3rd party product is not an good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to adjust this file because it automatically added into your project after you build your cordova project.

Comment: But what, if I run that application without building it? For example by running that application insight a browser (for debugging). I still get the error, that "cordova.js" was not found. So the device will never be "ready"... for that I have to use a workaround, like (pseudocode): `if device=phone use deviceReady else use document ready`. Probably there is an better option?

Comment: you need to build the cordova project to your each platform.

Comment: you can't run directly into browser. it built special for device, not for browser.

Comment: okay... but how it's possible to debug DOM, DOM-manipulation, etc. if it not runs correctly @ an browser?

Comment: you can use ripple chrome extension :)

Comment: ...which doesn't run stable and correct. It only supports cordova 2.0 and till now, I spaned a lot of time to make it running without any sustainable success

Comment: which platform you want to build? android or ios?